# Installing ant using homebrew on MAC OS X 10.11 not working properly

Tags: java, macos, bash, ant, homebrew

I installed Apache ant on my MAC OS X 10.11 today using Homebrew.
I saw following warning after running  ***brew install ant*** command on MAC terminal : -

> **Warning:** ant-1.9.6 already installed, it's just not linked.

Then I tried to check if ant is working properly or not by typing **ant -version** command on MAC Terminal window. I am receiving following error :

> **-bash: ant: command not found**

Is it because my ANT HOME Path is not set properly or it is not able to find the JAVA PATH ?

Comment: what is the output of `brew link -v ant`?

Comment: @cel ...Thanks. I think your suggestion fixed the problem.

Comment: @cel ,  ant -version worked like a charm after typing your command as suggested. But I do not know what just happened as I am kind of new to Homebrew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

brew installs software into a special directory named `Cellar`. After installation executables are linked symbolically to `/usr/local/bin`. This folder is in your `PATH` and therefore you can directly call all executables by typing the command.

---

```
Warning: ant-1.9.6 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

If you see this warning, the package is in Cellar, but not linked to `/usr/local/bin`. A simple `brew link ant` will do the linking step for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info